# Should i use query_posts() when i need to query for pages instead of posts?

Tags: wordpress, loops

What i wanted to do in my WP site is to display pages instead of posts, so i learned that you can do that by using the function **query_posts()**, and change the post_type parameter to 'page'. But then i read the documentation in the codex web page, and it says that you shouldn't use this function ever, because it runs too many queries unnecessary. They recommend to use the hook **pre_get_posts**. But when i read its documentation it says:

> "pre_get_posts cannot be used to alter the query for Page requests (page templates) because 'is_page', 'is_singular', 'pagename' and other properties (depending if pretty permalinks are used) are already set by the parse_query() method."

I'm not sure if this means that the only way is to use query_posts() and if that implies to run more queries. I'm worried about this because my WP site will have hundreds of pages, maybe more.

Comment: Write a custom query to get pages.

Comment: Where are you displaying these pages? On a page? We might need a bit more info to answer this question.